# Not able to apply Styles for a element targeted with document.getElementsByClassName()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to change the style of a dropdown by adjusting its top value to align it. Since the element is coming from drupal(CMS tool) end its configured in such a way that just there are classes attached to it so to change the styling (This style is just for the admin view where the content is authored) i need to target any of the attached classes to get that element but I get a htmlcollection  and even converting it to an array to change the style  doesnt help.

```
<ul class="selectBox-dropdown-menu selectBox-options form-control-selectBox-dropdown-menu form-select-selectBox-dropdown-menu news-feed-dropdown" style="width: 78.1125px;top: 210px;"><li class="selectBox-selected"><a rel="All">Show All</a></li><li class=""><a rel="announcement_post">Announcements</a></li><li class=""><a rel="blog">Blogs</a></li><li class=""><a rel="promotions">Promotions/New Hires</a></li><li class=""><a rel="shoutouts">Shoutouts</a></li></ul>
```

this is the dropdown which needs to be styled and the js code which i have done so far is as follows.

```
 var options = document.getElementsByClassName("selectBox-dropdown-menu");
 console.log("triggered");
 options[0].style.top = "174px";
```

the unordered list is initially hidden and once on click display is changed to block, hope i have given all the information needed the above issue can be solved in either plain js or jquery anything will help ,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be, you are trying to access DOM elements before they have rendered.
Keep you scripts at bottom and see if that works. Check out below example:

```html
<body>
  <h3>Try This</h3>
  <ul class="selectBox-dropdown-menu selectBox-options form-control-selectBox-dropdown-menu form-select-selectBox-dropdown-menu news-feed-dropdown" style="width: 78.1125px;top: 210px;">
    <li class="selectBox-selected"><a rel="All">Show All</a></li>
    <li class=""><a rel="announcement_post">Announcements</a></li>
    <li class=""><a rel="blog">Blogs</a></li>
    <li class=""><a rel="promotions">Promotions/New Hires</a></li>
    <li class=""><a rel="shoutouts">Shoutouts</a></li>
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var options = document.getElementsByClassName('selectBox-dropdown-menu');
    console.log('triggered');
    options[0].style.position = 'relative';
    options[0].style.top = '174px';
  </script>
</body>
```